# LabJackPython Installation in PsychoPy

Tags: python, terminal, module, modulenotfounderror, psychopy

I am on Mac (most recent OS). I am attempting to Install [LabJackPython](https://labjack.com/pages/support?doc=%2Fsoftware-driver%2Fexample-codewrappers%2Flabjackpython-for-ud-exodriver-u12-windows-mac-linux%2F) and [labjack-ljm](https://labjack.com/pages/support?doc=%2Fsoftware-driver%2Fexample-codewrappers%2Fpython-for-ljm-windows-mac-linux%2F) into PsychoPy.

I am following the instructions linked above to install the two packages into PsychoPy using the terminal. (pip install [package name]) It installs and gives me the following message:

```
"Successfully installed [package name]-[X.X.X]"
```

However, I am receiving the following error message when I run the code for my experiment:

```
"ImportError: No module named [packagename]"
```

The code I have tried running include (each line separately):

```
from LabJackPython import u3

from labjack-ljm import u3

import u3
```

I believe it is being installed into the wrong version of Python as when I type "pip uninstall [package name]" it provides the following:

```
> Found existing installation: labjack-ljm 1.21.0

> Uninstalling labjack-ljm-1.21.0:

> Would remove:

> /Users/djaro1/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/labjack/*
```

However, I tried to target the correct directory using the following code and it didn't work.

`pip install labjack-ljm -t C:\djaro\Applications\PsychoPy.app\Contents\Resources\lib\python3.8`

I have tried other methods of targeting the directory above without any success.

I have also followed the instructions on this page about adding custom modules to no success:

https://psychopy.org/recipes/addCustomModules.html

Let me know if you have any suggestions or can help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In PsychoPy 2023.1 available on GitHub you can install packages from within the app in the tools menu. It installs to your own user space, so you don't need admin rights, but other users won't have access. It any such packages will also then persist across PsychoPy installations because they aren't in Program Files where they will be removed by a reinstall

hope that helps